# Are there gas stoves with flame sensors and autmatic gas shutoff?

Tags: gas, stove

Are there any gas stoves with built in automatic safety shutoff features? For example, if I turn on gas but the burner didn't go on and the gas is running, is there a gas stove that would automatically shut off if burner didn't turn on?

Comment: I thought most newer/recent(last thirty years) ones would have a flame sensor to shut off the gas if no flame.  Most questions on here that is one of the first things to check if gas does not work.

Comment: "Are there any" is something of a Shopping Question...

Comment: Yes, there are.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - I have one in my kitchen!

Next to each gas burner is a spark igniter and a thermocouple.  To light the burner, I have to press down the knob to first light the burner, and then allow a few seconds for the thermocouple to warm up.

If I release the knob too early, or the burner blows out, then the gas shuts off.

Comment: It's comes as a part of gas hob ? Can you share the product link please

Comment: @Amogam it looks like mine is now obsolete, but here is a newer version https://www.aeg.co.uk/kitchen/cooking/hobs/gas-hob/hgb64200sm2/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of handling this. When I bought my Kitchenaid gas cooktop, I found out that the cheaper model would just try to automatically ignite the flame (i.e., same as when you first turn a burner on) if it did not detect a flame. Which results in lots of annoying clicking if the sensor gets dirty and tries to ignite when it is not necessary.

On the other hand, I found out that the most expensive model would actually electrically close the gas valve if it had a problem. That might sound like a great feature, but it also means (confirmed by the user's manual) that if there is no electric power then you can't turn on a burner (i.e., light it with a match) because the valve would be closed. That doesn't work well if you (a) want to be able to cook during a power outage and/or (b) are an Orthodox Jew and want to be able to cook on certain Jewish holidays.

So not all safety features are 100% "good". (Kind of like tamper-resistant receptacles are great for protecting kids but make it tough for adults with arthritis or other problems that affect hand strength plugging in things.)